# Java Expression

Tags: java, expression

I have specify code as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> filters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
filters.put("deleted", false);
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : filters.entrySet()) {
     String key   = entry.getKey();                       
     Object value = entry.getValue();           **// No evaluation**
     Expression<?> exp = (Expression<?>) entry.getValue();  **// Error**
}
```

Why java not evaluated and produce error?

Comment: What do you mean, it's not evaluating? And what do you mean, an error? What kind of error? Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

It fails because you cannot cast a `Boolean` to an `Expression<?>`.

When you put `false` into the map, it will autobox to a `Boolean` object. The class `Boolean` does not extend any `Expression` interface or class. I don't really know what that `Expression` type you have is.

Comment: In my code, I have specify entityClass that is contain a column name 'deleted' type 'boolean',
I want to filter all the data by compare to the column deleted=false.

Sorry...for the "Object value = entry.getValue();" --> this is ok.

Next line (I try to get the expression in String format), "Expression<?> exp = (Expression<?>) entry.getValue()", I got message: (java.lang.ClassCastException) java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String)

I really don't have idea how get the expression, something "deleted = false"

Comment: Well, if you have all the expressions and need to find the deleted ones, you need to loop through them and check that `!expression.isDeleted()`. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this map. It does not contain `Expression`s, and thus, you cannot cast the value to an `Expression`.